# transformar objetos em lista quando a resolução for menos que X

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Preciso alterar uma renderização, para mostrar uma caixa de seleção caso a resolução do dispositivo seja menor que X

exemplo:
mostrar radio's buttons e caso a resolução da tela for menor que X ele vira um select

Comment: Acho que a melhor forma de fazer isso seria criar das duas formas e mostrar apenas uma quando for cada caso. Brincando de `display: block;` e `display: none;`

Comment: Acrescentando o que o Leon disse usa com mediaquerie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a solução de ocultar o conteúdo usando o `display:block` e `display:none`, para isso utilize as condicionais de *css* `max-width`.

Segue exemplo:

CSS:

```
* { -ie-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
body{ background: #EEE;}
.box_form { width: 800px; margin:50px auto; max-width: 100%; background: #FFF; box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0 0 10px; padding: 30px;}
select, label { padding: 10px;}
.desktop { display: block;}
.mobile { display: none;}

@media(max-width:480px){
    .desktop { display: none;}
    .mobile { display: block;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<div class="box_form">
    <form action="">

        <div class="desktop">
            <input type="radio" id="resp1" value="1" name="pergunta1">
            <label for="resp1">Alternativa 1</label>

            <input type="radio" id="resp2" value="2" name="pergunta1">
            <label for="resp2">Alternativa 2</label>
        </div>

        <div class="mobile">
            <select name="pergunta1" id="pergunta1">
                <option value="">Alternativa 1</option>
                <option value="">Alternativa 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```